# Does "ever more" sound correct here?

Tags: meaning

I'm not quite sure if "ever more" sounds right in this sentence:

*The internet is revolutionising ever more professional sectors.​*

I've thought about "increasingly more" but that sounds redundant. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> The internet is revolutionizing ever more professional sectors.​

Does make sense. You're saying that the Internet has and continues to revolutionize professional sectors.

But you could also say to be more clear:

> The internet will continue to revolutionizing professional sectors.​

By stating "continue to" you are suggesting that it always has been without directly stating it.

Comment: "The internet will continue to *revolutionizing* professional sectors.​" should be "The internet will continue to *revolutionize* professional sectors.​"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but "The internet will continue revolutionizing professional sectors" doesn't indicate a steady increase in the amount of sectors that are being revolutionised. For now, the only suggestion that conveys this is A.P.'s "The internet is revolutionising an ever greater number of professional sectors".

That said, you mentioned that my original sentence does make sense, which I understand means that it's grammatically correct, and that it conveys the continual increase in sectors becoming revolutionised.

Answer (score 0):

Try: *The internet is revolutionising more and more professional sectors.​*

Or: *The internet is revolutionising an ever greater number of professional sectors.​*

Or: *The internet is revolutionising more professional sectors every day.* (Again, implies a continuous process.)

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions sound fine, but is mine correct?

Comment: @Anthony I'm not 100% sure it's grammatically incorrect, but I *am* sure it sounds a bit awkward. It seems your sentence could mean that the *sectors* are becoming ever more professional all the time, while the internet continues to revolutionize them. Which is not what you're trying to say, as far as I can gather.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated my answer to include another suggestion.